# Ternary operator confusion in Java

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I am doing LeetCode 437 Path Sum III https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-iii/
and my original code is as follows which passed all tests:

```
public int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return pathSumStartWithRoot(root, sum) + pathSum(root.left, sum) + pathSum(root.right, sum);
    }
    
    private int pathSumStartWithRoot(TreeNode root, int sum) {
        if (root == null) return 0;
        int res = root.val == sum ? 1 : 0;
        return res
            + pathSumStartWithRoot(root.left, sum - root.val) 
            + pathSumStartWithRoot(root.right, sum - root.val);
    }
```

My confusion is from `int res = root.val == sum ? 1 : 0;` in the private method. When I tried to shorten my code, I deleted this line and changed the return value to

```
    return root.val == sum ? 1 : 0 
   + pathSumStartWithRoot(root.left, sum - root.val) + pathSumStartWithRoot(root.right, sum - root.val);
```

However, this change caused some tests to fail. For example,

> TreeNode: [1,-2,-3,1,3,-2,null,-1], Sum: -1

The correct output should be 4 but with this change the output is 3.

More surprisingly, when I change the order of addition, say put the ternary to the last:

```
        return pathSumStartWithRoot(root.left, sum - root.val) 
        + pathSumStartWithRoot(root.right, sum - root.val)
        + root.val == sum ? 1 : 0;
```

the output is changed to 2.

I really had no idea what happened here. In my opinion, the order of addition should not matter the final result. I'm not very familiar with the ternary operator and I guess this issue might be due to the incorrect use? I searched a lot on the Internet but still couldn't find out the reason. Thanks for anyone's explanation.

Comment: Put `root.val == sum ? 1 : 0` in `()`.

Comment: You need to take a look at operator precedence (and why parentheses matter in certain cases).

Comment: I really wish that programming teachers taught the proper use of parentheses.

Comment: @NomadMaker or just debugging.

Comment: The use of the debugger should be taught right after the students can handle a "Hello World" program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my opinion

Unfortunately, your opinion isn't relevant to the compiler.

```
int a = condition ? 1 : 0;
int b = a + c;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int b = (condition ? 1 : 0) + c;
```

It's not equivalent to:

```
int b = condition ? 1 : 0 + c;
```

because that's the same as:

```
int b = condition ? 1 : (0 + c);
```

owing to `+` having higher precedence than `?:`. ([See table of precedence of the operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)).

So if you want to inline the conditional expression, you need to use parentheses to indicate the intended precedence.

```
return (root.val == sum ? 1 : 0)
    // ^-----------------------^ Extra parens.
   + pathSumStartWithRoot(root.left, sum - root.val)
   + pathSumStartWithRoot(root.right, sum - root.val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not even do that for interviews. That "shortening" code is irrelevant to algorithm design, and has nothing to do with efficiency (time or memory), I guess.

Another point is that [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) are not designed for writing one liners.

Just follow the conventions:

```
public class Solution {
    public final int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> prefixSum = new HashMap<>();
        prefixSum.put(0, 1);
        return helper(root, 0, sum, prefixSum);
    }

    private static final int helper(TreeNode node, int currSum, int target, HashMap<Integer, Integer> prefixSum) {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;

        currSum += node.val;
        int res = prefixSum.getOrDefault(currSum - target, 0);
        prefixSum.put(currSum, 1 + prefixSum.getOrDefault(currSum, 0));
        res += helper(node.left, currSum, target, prefixSum) + helper(node.right, currSum, target, prefixSum);
        prefixSum.put(currSum, prefixSum.get(currSum) - 1);
        return res;
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-iii/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Answer (score 0):

`+` operator precedence is higher than ternary operator `?:` so you code

```
pathSumStartWithRoot(root.left, sum - root.val) 
 + pathSumStartWithRoot(root.right, sum - root.val)+ root.val
```

this addition part will works first then ternary part like

```
return ((pathSumStartWithRoot(root.left, sum - root.val) 
        + pathSumStartWithRoot(root.right, sum - root.val)
        + root.val) == sum) ? 1 : 0;
```

So you can use bracket for tenary portion

```
return pathSumStartWithRoot(root.left, sum - root.val) 
        + pathSumStartWithRoot(root.right, sum - root.val)
        + (root.val == sum ? 1 : 0);
```